# Using target as iframe for dynamically created php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a dynamic php script, whose response I wish to show in an iframe

```
<div id="plotpnl">
    <b>Graph :</b><br><br>
    <form action="create_charts.php" method="post" target="iframe_a">
        <font color="#587E91"><b>Strats :  </b></font>
        <input type="text" style="width:220px; margin:0 auto;" name="stratlist" placeholder="comma separated strat list"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <font color="#587E91"><b>Columns :  </b></font>
        <input type="text" style="width:265px; margin:0 auto;" name="collist" placeholder="comma separated columns list" />&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <input type="submit" value="Plot" style="color:#587E91;font-weight:bold"/> &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Wipe" style="color:#587E91;font-weight:bold" onClick="this.form.reset()"/>
        <iframe width="100%" height="300px" src="DUMMY.php" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
    </form>
</div>
```

when i give target as_blank, it works as expected(opens in new tab) however im unable to open it in iframe. Maybe thats due to the the way create_pnl.php is written. (It takes form arguments and runs a shell script to create some.page.php) This "some.filename.php" is the one which I need to display in iframe.
My create_charts.php is as follows

```
$stratlist=$_POST['stratlist']; 
$collist=$_POST['collist']; 

#echo "stratlist : $stratlist , collist : $collist , inst_list : $instlist"; 

$cmd1 = "makeaphpcode.sh \"$stratlist\" \"$collist\" \"pnl\""; 
exec($cmd1); 


$filename="plot.pnl.$stratlist.$collist.php"; 
$filename=str_replace(',','.',$filename); 
$filename=str_replace(' ','',$filename); 


if (!headers_sent($file, $line)){ 
   header("Location:mysite.com/$filename"); 
   exit; 
}else{ 
   echo "Headers sent in $file on line $line"; 
   exit;
```

I am unable to figure out why the content is not redirected to iframe when i use target=iframe_a. The code is shown fine if I use target="_blank"